# Copy edit and insert or update a mongo document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

We have got some changes in our project so writing a migration script(first time). I will explain it a little whatever required here:
Note -  for some reasons, we store `date` as a json `{date:DD, month:MM, year :YYYY, ...}`

- Collections - Admin, User
- Admin - _id, name::String, reg_date::ISODate,etc.
- User  - _id, name::String, admin_id:Admin._id, formdata:JSON , formname::String()
- reg_date is divided into two parts `reg_date >= 01012014` then `formname = "H26"` else  `formname = "H24"`

Now the new change is for which the migration is needed:

- Change in dates

  - If `reg_date >= 01012014 && reg_date <= 01112014` then `formname = "H25"` and
  - if  `reg_date < 01012014` then  `formname = "H24"`
    else ( if `reg_date > 01112014`)
  - then `formname = "H26101"`
- Migration script if there is a user form which has `reg_date > 01112014` then convert it to `H26101`

My following code is not working:

```
db.Admin.find().forEach(function(admin){ 
   if(hasH26101Date(admin.reg_date)){
      var copy = db.user.find({ "admin_id" :admin._id, "formname": "H26"});     //Copy document
      if (jsonDataExist(copy)){
         var new_data  = processData(copy.formdata);
         copy[formdata] = new_data;
         copy[formname] = "H26101";
         var new_query = { "admin_id":admin._id, "formname":"H26101"};
         db.user.update(new_query, {$set:{formdata:new_data,formname:"H26101"}},
         {upsert:true}});
    }
   }
});
}
```

In the last line of code - If document with new_query exists then formname n formdata in same document otherwise insert a new copy.